# Log SQL Messages in Pentaho

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I'm not familiar with Pentaho. I've just take charge of an old Project.

At one step, a stored procedure is called on a SQL Server DB. The procedure show a lot of messages through `PRINT` or `RAISEERROR(@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT` instuctions.
Is there a way to log these messages in Pentaho ?

I tried to increase the log level in Pentaho and to active the *Logging and Performance Monitoring* but I still not see them anywhere...

Comment: Read [This Article]. Is not for Pentaho, but logic you can use anywhere.

Comment: Thanks but the link is missing...

Comment: Sorry, [Here](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-implement-error-handling-in-sql-server/) is article.

Comment: I quickly read the article but I don't think it can help. I already have an error handling in the procedure with a transaction managment near from what is described in the article.
This is just my real problem : I have an error with transaction managment in a specific case and I don't understand what Pentaho really does with transactions because when I try to call my SP in DataGrip or SSMS I don't note the same behavior despite the call is done in a transcation or not.
So see the execution messages could really help to understand.